# Hierarchal Regex in java

Tags: java, regex

```
  {
    schoolObject:{
      schoolDetails:{
        PrincipleId:5706980052,
        isPaymentDone:false,
        classId:"500720478039",
        classDetails:[
          {
            classId:123591,
            studentList:[
              {
                studentType:0,
                categoryName:"",
                lastYearFee:{
                  amount:10.00,
                  denomination:"INR"
                },
                currentYearFee:{
                  amount:49.99,
                  denomination:"INR"
                }
              },
              {
                studentType:1,
                categoryName:"",
                lastYearFee:{
                  amount:5.00,
                  denomination:"INR"
                },
                currentYearFee:{
                  amount:15.00,
                  denomination:"INR"
                }
              }
            ],
            ItemId:1234567,
            schoolInternalId:"976-345272383",
            netAmount:{
              amount:60.00,
              denomination:"INR"
            },
            studentAccountId:953217682525
          }
  }
```

So, I have to parse this String and write a validation function such that sum of lastYearFee and currentYearFee should match the netChange for studentType 0.

Here in this example: for student Type 0, lastYearFee is 10.00 and currentYearFee is 49.99 and Netcharge are 60.00. The sum is 59.99 which is not matching with NetCharge. So I have to add 0.01 in currentYearFee.

The solution that I have in mind.. 
search for lastYearFee, search for current year Fee, search for and netCharge. check the difference and adjust the currentYearFee. But I am not to write REGEX for this. Let's say we assume this structure never changes.How would we write the solution ?

**Problem 2:**
Challenge: 
I have to make logic somewhat generic.. 
I want to write a regex to extract infromation..

1. Get the studentList :: schoolObject followed by classDetails followed by studentList.. 
   so this would give

   ```
   studentList:[
     {
       studentType:0,
       categoryName:"",
       lastYearFee:{
         amount:10.00,
         denomination:"INR"
       },
       currentYearFee:{
         amount:49.99,
         denomination:"INR"
       }
     },
     {
       studentType:1,
       categoryName:"",
       lastYearFee:{
         amount:5.00,
         denomination:"INR"
       },
       currentYearFee:{
         amount:15.00,
         denomination:"INR"
       }
     }
   ]
   ```

   Now there can be multiple entries, for studentType 0,1,2... out of them extract only 0... There can be multiple entries in studentType:0 itself. like here are only currentYearFee and lastYearFee is present. there can be more...
2. Now the amount in schoolObject followed by classDetails followed by netCharge...
3. get the different , and modify the last item in studentList.

Note: This looks like JSON but there is no double quote in fields name. I can not convert it in JSON. I have to modify the string..

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel you could process this with a Javascript Engine (your data seem to be valid js objects) and get the resulting objects from it, to process them with java. But I'm not sure if I would do this, it's more of a hack than a proper solution.

Comment: This has to be done in JAVA. yes it's a short term hack. Ideally I would never modify string. I would use Expression like Fusion to modify it. But Hack is what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, if it's a potentially recursive language, you can't parse it with a regex. You'll need to write a parser for it. Perhaps you can find a JSON parser that's tolerant about quotes in field names. Or you can write a simple one on your own using a tool like antlr.

Comment: You know that there is a Javascript engine as part of Java, don't you?

Comment: @saurabhagarwal I know this has to be done in java, that's why I'm talking about javascript engines. They are part of the standard java library.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks for information... Didn't know that.. thanks.. will look at it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I can add quotes around the fields . but after modifying the string I have to modify it back to remove the string. Downstream system expect the output without quotes

Comment: Use the [config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) tool from Typesafe. They can handle this format natively.